# Pass data to another page form totally filled asp.net full

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, I dont get send my data to another page, basically
I need click on date-item link and pass data to another page form filled with data from the first page:

```
    @model List<PontoWeb.Models.Ponto>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Relatório de Ponto";
    ViewBag.MesAtual = System.DateTime.Now.Month;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div  class="container-fluid">

    <div  class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Marcar Ponto", "MarcarPonto")</li>

            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ir para Mês Anterior", "MostraPontoMesAnterior",new { ViewBag.MesAgora})</li>

            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ir para Próximo Mês", "MostraPontoMesFuturo", new { ViewBag.MesAgora })</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">


    <table class="table table-hover">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data</th>
                <!-- <th>Dia da Semana</th> -->
                <th>Entrada</th>
                <th>Saída Almoço</th>
                <th>Entrada Almoço</th>
                <th>Saída</th>
                <th>Saldo Diário</th>
                <th>Saldo Acumulado</th> 
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {

                <tr>

                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Data, "MarcarPonto", new { data = item.Data, @entrada = item.Entrada, saida_almoco = item.Saida_Almoco, entrada_almoco = item.Entrada_Almoco, saida = item.Saida }) </td>
                    <td>@item.Entrada </td>
                    <td>@item.Saida_Almoco</td>
                    <td>@item.Entrada_Almoco </td>
                    <td>@item.Saida</td>
                    <td>@item.Saldo_Dia</td>
                    <td>@item.Saldo_Acumulado</td>
                </tr>

            }



        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
```

to This page

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Marcar Ponto";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Marcador de Ponto Diário</h2>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ir para Ponto", "MostraPonto")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <form class="form" action="/Ponto/Marcar">


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="data">Data:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="data" name="data" value="data">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
                <label for="entrada">Entrada:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="entrada" name="entrada" value="00:00" max="23:59">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="saida_almoco">Saída Almoço:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="saida_almoco" name="saida_almoco" value="00:00"  max="23:59">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="entrada_almoco">Entrada Almoço:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="entrada_almoco" name="entrada_almoco" value="00:00"  max="23:59">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="saida">Saída:</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control" id="saida" name="saida" value="00:00" max="23:59">
            </div>



            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Gravar</button>

</form>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('data').valueAsDate = new Date();
</script>
```

My controller:

```
    using PontoWeb.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace PontoWeb.Controllers
{
    public class PontoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Ponto
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult MostraPonto() {
            Operacoes operacoes = new Operacoes();
            int MesCorrente=  DateTime.Now.Month;

            ViewBag.MesAgora = MesCorrente;

            return View(operacoes.Select(MesCorrente));
        }



        public ActionResult MarcarPonto() {

            return View();
        }

        // [Route("MarcarPonto/{data}")]
        public ActionResult MarcarPontoDados(string data, DateTime entrada, DateTime saida_almoco, DateTime entrada_almoco, DateTime saida)
        {
            Operacoes op = new Operacoes();
            ViewBag.Ponto.Data = op.SelectData(data);
            //ViewBag.Ponto.Data = data;
            //ViewBag.Ponto.Entrada = entrada;
            //ViewBag.Ponto.Saida_Almoco = saida_almoco;
            //ViewBag.Ponto.Entrada_Almoco = entrada_almoco;
            //ViewBag.Ponto.Saida = saida;


            return View("MarcarPonto");
        }

        public ActionResult Marcar( string data,  DateTime entrada, DateTime saida_almoco, DateTime entrada_almoco, DateTime saida ) {
            Ponto ponto = new Ponto();
            ponto.Data = data ;
            ponto.Entrada = entrada.Hour.ToString("00.##") + ":" + entrada.Minute.ToString("00.##"); 
            ponto.Saida_Almoco = saida_almoco.Hour.ToString("00.##") + ":" + saida_almoco.Minute.ToString("00.##");
            ponto.Entrada_Almoco = entrada_almoco.Hour.ToString("00.##") + ":" + entrada_almoco.Minute.ToString("00.##");
            ponto.Saida = saida.Hour.ToString("00.##") + ":" + saida.Minute.ToString("00.##");

            Operacoes operacoes = new Operacoes();
            operacoes.Add(ponto);

            return Redirect("MostraPonto");
        }

        public ActionResult MostraPontoMesAnterior(int MesAgora) {

            Operacoes operacoes = new Operacoes();
            int MesAnterior = MesAgora - 1;

            ViewBag.MesAgora = MesAnterior;

            return View("MostraPonto",operacoes.Select(MesAnterior));

        }

        public ActionResult MostraPontoMesFuturo(int MesAgora)
        {

            Operacoes operacoes = new Operacoes();
            int MesFuturo = MesAgora + 1;

            ViewBag.MesAgora = MesFuturo;
            return View("MostraPonto", operacoes.Select(MesFuturo));


        }

    }
}
```

I need get from page1

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Data, "MarcarPonto", new { data = item.Data, @entrada = item.Entrada, saida_almoco = item.Saida_Almoco, entrada_almoco = item.Entrada_Almoco, saida = item.Saida }) </td>
```

To page2 filled.

x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x
x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x
x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x
x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x

Comment: Can you explain which page corresponds to which controller ActionResult method?

Comment: You need to add parameter to `MarcarPonto` action method and use that to fill the data needed for the view. The html helper is already rendering the anchor tag with the needed querystring. Your parameter names should match with querystring keys

Comment: <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.Data, "MarcarPonto", new { data = item.Data, @entrada = item.Entrada, saida_almoco = item.Saida_Almoco, entrada_almoco = item.Entrada_Almoco, saida = item.Saida }) </td>                                                                                                           
                                                                                                            
                                                                                                            
 public ActionResult MarcarPonto() {

            return View();
 }